# Python multiline alignment using format

Tags: python, string, format, alignment

### Background:

When I do data cleaning, I want print my arg name and its value in lines. However  args' name vary at length and so do their values. For clarity, I want align arg's name to the left and arg's value to the right in each line.

For instance, I want result like following:

Output:

```
Arg1               :           value1
Arg2222222222222222:           value2
Arg3               : value33333333333
```

### Current method:

Suppose I have 3 args and 3 values.

```
name_list = ['Arg1','Arg2222222222222222','Arg3']
value_list = ['value1', 'value2', 'value33333333333']
```

Using following code, I can print it clearly.

Code:

```
name_list = ['Arg1','Arg2222222222222222','Arg3']
value_list = ['value1', 'value2', 'value33333333333']
padding1 = max(map(len, name_list))
padding2 = max(map(len, value_list))
print("padding1 = {}, padding2 = {}".format(padding1,padding2))
for num in range(len(name_list)):
    print('{0}: {1}'.format(name_list[num].ljust(padding1), value_list[num].rjust(padding2)))
```

Output:

```
padding1 = 19, padding2 = 16
Arg1               :           value1
Arg2222222222222222:           value2
Arg3               : value33333333333
```

### Question:

Can we use **less code** to achieve the same goal? Or, can we do it more **specifically**?

Thank you for your help, guys!

### Some Citation

[String alignment when printing in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153862/string-alignment-when-printing-in-python)

[python 3 string formatting (alignment)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19162621/python-3-string-formatting-alignment)

Comment: You are doing it just right. Code must not only be efficient but also verbose. The only correction I would suggest for this is that you use f'strings instead of `format`, the former helps readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not much, but if using fstrings, you could do

```
for name, value in zip(name_list, value_list):
    print(f'{name:<{padding1}}:{value:>{padding2}}')    #fstring version
```

The `<` and `>` are for left and right alignment respectively.

Output will be

```
Arg1               :          value1
Arg2222222222222222:          value2
Arg3               :value33333333333
```

See [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec).

Answer (score 2):

Using less code, and only missing the separator `:`

```py
import pandas as pd

name_list = ['Arg1','Arg2222222222222222','Arg3']
value_list = ['value1', 'value2', 'value33333333333']

print(pd.DataFrame(value_list, index=name_list, columns=['']))  # [''] hides the column name (default: 0)
```

Output:

```
Arg1                           value1
Arg2222222222222222            value2
Arg3                 value33333333333
```